# How to allow unauthorized request for the first time and then require authorization?

Tags: java, spring, request, authorization, endpoint

So, we are implementing this special kind of authorization, where after logging in, user is presented with basic dashboard. When trying to get to another location, he is asked to authorize with password.

The thing is that in order to present the basic dashboard, some requests are sent and need to come with 200 response, while the rest just returns error message and redirects to authorization screen.

To summarize, we're gonna have 3 kinds of endpoints:
- blocked, until user authorizes
- allowed to return proper data for the first time while each consecutive request will require authorization
- no authorization required

I cannot find a way to overcome the 2nd type. Is there a way to record the number of requests sent per specific endpoint? Or is there any way to actually allow first unauthorized use and then required authorization?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to authenticate user without any role the first time that users access to yours controllers.

Then when he try again to access you could sent them to login process if user is logged without role.

To securize this methods could use the annotation below:

```
@Secure("IsAuthenticated()==false || (IsAuthenticated() && hasRole("WRITE"))")
```

To securize manually a user should use the `SecurityContextHolder` class